# Add Banner in the PLP page

Tags: product, category, extensions, promotional-banner

I want to add banners on the PLP page that redirects to the linked category.
Is there any extension or customizations that help me to do this?

Image is an attached with this question.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build a custom module that creates a **Widget** and adds it to the catalog_category_view.xml via **cms block**

define your required layout in the template.phtml

Create a CMS block - Call via the widget.

Answer (score 0):

I have created something like this where I created a module which adds a content area to the category in the admin and once updated outputs on the PLP page at the bottom.

This uses page builder by default but I am sure it would use the standard wysiwyg editor if page builder is disabled.

**Create the file & folder structure like attached image.**

[image]

1. Controller/Index/Save.php

```
namespace Vendor\BottomDescription\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Save extends Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $_resultJsonFactory;
    protected $_helper;
    protected $_messageManage;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
        \Primrose\BottomDescription\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManage,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory, 
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_messageManage = $messageManage;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

        try {
            $type = $this->getRequest()->getParam('type');
            $this->_logger = $this->_helper->getLogger();

            if($type == "export") {
                $this->_messageManage->addSuccess("Export started.");
                $this->_helper->export();
            } elseif($type == "import") {
                $this->_messageManage->addSuccess("Import started.");
                $this->_helper->import();
            }

        } catch (\Throwable $exception){
            $this->_logger->info($exception->getMessage());
        }

        $this->_messageManage->addSuccess("It's successful.");
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

2. etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_BottomDescription">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

3. etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="bottomdescription" frontName="bottomdescription">
            <module name="Vendor_BottomDescription" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

4. Helper/Data.php

```
 
namespace Vendor\BottomDescription\Helper;
 
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
 
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    const EXPORT_FILE = "import/bottom_description.csv"; 

    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_scopeOverriddenValue;
    protected $_categoryCollection;
    protected $_categoryRepository;
    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_directoryList;
    protected $_csv;
    protected $_file;
    protected $_directory;
    protected $_logger;
 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\ScopeOverriddenValue $scopeOverriddenValue,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollection,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
        \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csv,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $file
    )
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_scopeOverriddenValue = $scopeOverriddenValue;
        $this->_categoryCollection = $categoryCollection;
        $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->_csv = $csv;
        $this->_file = $file;
        $this->_directory = $fileSystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
        parent::__construct($context);

        $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/bottom_description.log');
        $this->_logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
        $this->_logger->addWriter($writer);
    }
 
    // readCsv()
    public function import() 
    {
        $cnt = 0;
        $rootDirectory = $this->_directoryList->getRoot();
        $csvFile = $rootDirectory . "/var/" . self::EXPORT_FILE;
        $data = "";
        $adminStoreId = 0;
        $currentStoreId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

        try {
            $this->_logger->info("Import started:");       

            if ($this->_file->isExists($csvFile)) {
                //set delimiter, for tab pass "\t"
                $this->_csv->setDelimiter(",");
                //get data as an array
                $data = $this->_csv->getData($csvFile);
                if (!empty($data)) {
                    // ignore first header column and read data
                    foreach (array_slice($data, 1) as $key => $value) {
                        $id = trim($value['0']);
                        $storeId = trim($value['1']);
                        $desc = trim($value['2']);

                        // Save into the default store

                        $category = $this->_categoryRepository->get($id, $adminStoreId);
                        $category->setStoreId($adminStoreId);
                        $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($adminStoreId);

                        if($category && !$category->getBottomDescription()) {
                            $category->setBottomDescription($desc);
                            $this->_categoryRepository->save($category);
                            $cnt++;
                        }

                        // Save into the current store
                        $category = $this->_categoryRepository->get($id, $currentStoreId);
                        $category->setStoreId($currentStoreId);
                        $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($currentStoreId);

                        if($category && !$category->getBottomDescription()) {
                            if($currentStoreId == $storeId) {
                                $category->setBottomDescription($desc);
                                $this->_categoryRepository->save($category);
                                $cnt++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $this->_logger->info("Imported count:" . $cnt);

            } else {
                $this->_logger->info('Csv file not exist');
            }
        } catch (FileSystemException $e) {
            $this->_logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }

        $this->_logger->info("Import ended");       
        return true;
    }

    // writeCsv()
    public function export() 
    { 
        $cnt = 0;
        $filepath = self::EXPORT_FILE;
        $this->_directory->create('import');
        $stream = $this->_directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();

        $this->_logger->info("Export started:");

        $header = ['id', 'store_id', 'bottom_description'];
        $stream->writeCsv($header);

        // $storeIds = array_keys($this->_storeManager->getStores(true));
        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $categories = $this->_categoryCollection->create()                              
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if($category->getBottomDescription()) {
                    $data = [];
                    $data[] = $category->getId();
                    $data[] = $storeId;
                    $data[] = $category->getBottomDescription();
                    $stream->writeCsv($data);

                    $cnt++;
            }
        }

        $this->_logger->info("Exported count:" . $cnt);
        $this->_logger->info("Export ended");
    }

    public function getLogger() {
        return $this->_logger;
    }
}
```

5. Setup/Patch/Data/AddBottomDescriptionCategoryAttribute.php

```
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\BottomDescription\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

class AddBottomDescriptionCategoryAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'bottom_description',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Bottom Description',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'sort_order' => 4,
                'source' => '',
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'bottom_description');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
        
        ];
    }
}
```

6. view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="bottom_description" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="60" formElement="wysiwyg">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">100px</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item><!-- this validates it as required -->
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Bottom Descritpion</label>
                <dataScope>bottom_description</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <wysiwyg class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg">
                    <settings>
                        <rows>8</rows>
                        <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                    </settings>
                </wysiwyg>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

7. view/frontend/layout/catelog_category_view/xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="bottom.description" template="Primrose_BottomDescription::product/list/bottom_description.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

8. view/frontend/templates/product/list/bottom_description.phtml

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Category view template: Adding content block to the bottom of the plp.
 */

?>

<?php if ($_bottomDescription = $block->getCurrentCategory()->getBottomDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-bottom-description">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($block->getCurrentCategory(), $_bottomDescription, 'bottom_description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

9. composer.json

```
    "name": "vendor/bottomdescription",
    "description": "Adds content field at bottom on category pages that can be configured from admin.",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.5",
    "license": [
        "proprietary"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Andy",
        }
    ],
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\BottomDescription\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

10. registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_BottomDescription',
    __DIR__
);
```

Please remember to rename the **Vendor** to your client/company name in the app/code directory.

This should create a content block on the category page in the admin like so:

[image]

This will place a content block at the bottom of the plp page like so:

[image]

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any issues and please upvote if this works for you.